# Magento - Catalog Price Rules only working on some of the products

Tags: magento, product, catalog, rule

I want to apply a catalog price rule only on a certain category.
This works to a certain extent. The category has 109 products, but I can only see the reduced price on the frontend of like 20 of the 109 products. The rest is unchanged.

What could be the cause of this? If I manually edit the products the price rule is applied, but having to do this for 80+ products is a bit too much.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Magento has a weird way of storing and indexing pricing when there are pricing rules.

Try to run a cron job every few minutes or so.